# Reading a table through a html link using scan() function in R

Tags: r, vector, import

I am having trouble with doing one of the assignments for my uni.
My task is get the information from this link ("https://isor.univie.ac.at/about-us/People.html") and make it into a vector using the scan function in R.

```
datei <- scan("https://isor.univie.ac.at/about-us/People.html", what = list(name = "", room ="", email = "", website = ""))
datei
```

I have tried the code above, but the output is just messy. I need the information to be in a vector format, how should I approach this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: vector or table?

Comment: The html has a table, but I need to convert all information into vectors

Comment: Have you tried `rvest`? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html & https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/

Comment: Is it not possible with scan function?